# Probabalistic way to calculate limit of a sum

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, central-limit-theorem

I am following a course on stochastic processes. One question is to Calculate 
$$lim_{n\to \infty} \sum^n_{i=0} e^{-n} \frac{n^i}{i!}$$
I see that it looks like the expected value of $e^{-n} \frac{n^{i+1}}{i!}$ but i don't know how to proceed. 
I tried to use mathematica but i'm not sure this is correct.

> Solve[Integrate[E^(-n) n^(i + 1)/Factorial[i], {n, 0, x}] == 
>     1/2 Integrate[
>       E^(-n) n^(i + 1)/Factorial[i], {n, 0, Infinity}] , x, Reals]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yea i saw it after posting this, will close it now

Comment: I hope that the duplication mark does not discourage you; it simply means that this community has accumulated enough knowledge to readily answer your question. Especially, the user **Did**'s answer there provides a probabilistic solution.

Comment: Note that to make the argument formal you might want to consider probability generating functions/moment generating functions/characteristic functions, to show that the sum of $n$ i.i.d. $\mathrm{Pois}(1)$ random variables is indeed $\mathrm{Pois}(n)$ distributed.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Consider a sequence of independent and identically distributed $\mathrm{Pois}(1)$ distributed random variables, and apply the central limit theorem. The value should be $\frac12$.

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look again. Didn't see the poisson in there, clever!